# How to loop through an NSString and get a Substring?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I need to get a Substring from a NSString. I need to get the substring after `-` if it is followed by `E` until the next `-`

For example, I have this string A-BB-CD-*EF_10AW*-ZWE_EG

I need to get the EF_10AW. Any idea on how can I iterate through an NSString and get a substring dynamically?

Comment: Use regular expressions.   I don't have access to Xcode now, but this expression creates a capturing good that returns EF_10AW given your test string:  ^.*-(?<a>E.*)-.*$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your string contains multiple string that starts with E and ends with - than you must have one solution that can find all those strings. For such solution please refer below code:

```
NSString *str = @"A-BB-CD-EF_10AW-ZWE_EG";

NSArray *compArray = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"];

NSMutableArray *arrayStartWithE = [NSMutableArray array];

for (int i = 0; i < [compArray count]; i++) {
    if ([[compArray objectAtIndex:i] hasPrefix:@"E"]) {
        [arrayStartWithE addObject:[compArray objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
}
```

Here arraystartWithE will give you all those type of string. Hope this might help you.

Answer (score 0):

try this
splitArray = [yourString componentsSeparatedByString:@"-E"];

no need to manually loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *haystack = @"A-BB-CD-EF_10AW-ZWE_EG";
NSString *haystackPrefix = @"A-BB-CD-";
NSString *haystackSuffix = @"-ZWE_EG";
NSRange needleRange = NSMakeRange(haystackPrefix.length,
                              haystack.length - haystackPrefix.length - haystackSuffix.length);
NSString *needle = [haystack substringWithRange:needleRange];
NSLog(@"needle: %@", needle); // -> "hello World"
```